# Forward call to delegate at runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates

I have several subclasses of `UITableViewController` which contain cells of type `myCell` (a subclass of `UITableViewCell`). These cells contain `UITextField`s and are the delegates for these textfields. However, in rare cases, I would like to catch some of the calls to the delegates in the tableViewController (in particular, `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:`).

Is there a reasonable way to achieve this without having to subclass my cell ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your `myCell` class define its own protocol as well as a `delegate` property.

Then make the table view controller the delegate for each cell it creates. Then the table view controller can implement the cell's protocol methods.

Then the implementation of the cell class can call, when needed, the methods of its delegate.

Comment: I get this but I would like the calls to the delegate to depend only on the tableView itself. ie I am looking for a code where the cell would be completely agnostic to whether its delegate methods get overriden or not. Maybe I am just asking too much.

Comment: 1) You can't do that. 2) You shouldn't try to do that. It's too fragile. Make it explicit. Then it's a clear definition of duties. 3) OK, you can do that but it would be done by subclassing the cell. So either support subclassing or use the protocol approach.

Comment: Ok for 1). About 2), I am not sure. If my cell is used 100 times and that there are 2 places where I want to do this, then I am creating a lot of code for very little. Or my design is completely wrong from start.

Comment: Then option 3 is best. Subclassing.

Comment: Stick with subclassing as this is a case of specialization. It follows proven object oriented design patterns. The other solutions are object oriented spaghetti code and will only lead to confusion and heartache in the long run.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Thanks